# Top link configuration is webshpere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere-8, toplink

I am trying to configure toplink jar in WebSphere 8.5.5 version to use in our application. The configuration is not working in this version where as the same is working in 6.1 and 7.0 versions. Steps as follows

1. added toplink jar in websphere_Home/lib and tryied in websphere_Home/lib/ext folders
2. configured JVM options in "Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties".

Please suggest if any additional configurations needs to be done in 8.5.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

@meghanathch - Why don't you simply include toplink in your project?  If you're using Maven, Gradle, or Ant/Ivy, you could define the dependency.  If you're using Eclipse/RAD, you can include the jar in the project's lib directory.  If WAS doesn't initialize TopLink properly, you can try setting the Classloader Policy to PARENT_LAST or create an Isolated Shared Library.